# yii2 "$" Is not internal or external Command, executable program or batch file. ERROR

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yui-compressor

I am trying to minimize the assets in yii2 test project, but with no result. I used this tutorial: [HOW TO MINIMIZE THE ASSETS IN YII 2 FRAMEWORK](https://www.dunebook.com/how-to-minimize-the-assets-in-yii-2-framework/2/)

I use openserver. In assets directory I created a file named compression. In that file I put yuicompressor.jar(YUI compressor) and compiler.jar(Google Closure compiler).
[files screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilGqW.png)

After that, I tried to create configuration file for the compressor,
running this command in the openserver console(being in the project root):

```
$ ./yii asset/template assets/compression/config.php
```

But here I get the following error:

```
"$" Is not internal or external
Command, executable program or batch file.
```

Please help with this!

Comment: Try it without the `$` at the start. The `$` notation is usually used to signify that the command should be run in the command line

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried without  $ ,   like:    ./yii asset/template assets/compression/config.php, but thjatn I get this error: "." Is not internal or external
Command, executable program or batch file.

Comment: like:    ./yii asset/template assets/compression/config.php, but thjatn I get this error: "." Is not internal or external
Command, executable program or batch file.

Comment: ".....any first symbol...." Is not internal or external
Command, executable program or batch file.

Comment: I think , it may be something with path/ Wron path?

Comment: I use the last version of Openserver, the composer works fine. I can't uderstend why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a environmental variable / path problem.
Try the same command with `php` in front, possibly without the `./`.
Could also be that you need to use the entire path to php, like `/path/to/php yii asset/template assets/compression/config.php`.

Comment: Without "php"    and  "./" works. Like this: yii asset/template assets/compression/config.php

Comment: I also think it was an environmental variable / path problem. The local web server console in some cases was acting as cmd. And for example when I tried to set minimizing in yii2 using http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/ and https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/, I got another error, that java comands are not recognized in the web server console. Than I made synchronization between webserver console and cmd and I ran successfully commands like "yii asset/template assets/compression/config.php"       and   'java -jar compiler.jar --js {from} --js_output_file {to}'